# Zend Framework, FirePHP

Tags: zend-framework, firephp

I'm having a spot of bother getting anything to log with FirePHP and Zend Framework.
Firebug is installed and the site is in the allowed list. I don't know if there are any other tests I can do to check FirePHP.

Bootstrap :

```
protected function _initActionHelper()
{
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
}
```

Controller :

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $logger;

    public function init()
        {
            $this->logger = Zend_Registry::get('logger');
        }

        public function indexAction()
        {
            $this->logger->log('ALERT', Zend_Log::ALERT);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that firebug is actually working? I went around in circles for hours one day only to find out that firebug itself was not really working. I had to downgrade to Firebug 1.4.2 (which you can get from http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.4/ ).

I would put some simple javascript on the site with a console.log statement to test firebug first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.debug('testing firebug console');
</script>
```

If that is working I would then check to make sure that the firephp headers are actually being sent. If you open the **firebug** section in firefox and then go to the **net** tab you should be able to see the response headers sent from your site.

If the headers aren't being sent I'm not sure how much help I can be, but I would look into Zend_Wildfire ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.wildfire.html#zend.wildfire.chapter ) and see if there may be something there.

Comment: Yeah it was firebug at fault. I'm logging away now :)

Comment: There's a small error in the JS above. I tried to edit it but couldn't as it's only one character. The 'testing firebug' is missing the last quote.

Answer (score 0):

Reset of FireBug and re-install of FirePHP and it all started working.